# Gradle build fails when I use command line

Tags: gradle, command-line, build

I completed a test task in a company, which required to describe the process of building the task. And when I tried to build my project using Gradle, the process failed with this message:

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'testTask'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework:spring-core-test:6.0.6")
        classpath("org.springframework:spring-websocket:6.0.6")
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.0.4")
        classpath("com.mysql:mysql-connector-j:8.0.32")
    }

}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.6'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

group = 'ru.malkov'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
```

Need to add that build goes perfectly if I run it using IDEA, but fails if I use command line. Please, give me advice, what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that you're using correct java using

```
java -version
javac -version
```

Also verify that you run gradle using gradle wrapper

```
./gradlew clean bootRun
```